# What is wrong with my simple regex that accepts empty strings and apartment numbers?

Tags: regex

So I wanted to limit a textbox which contains an apartment number which is optional.

Here is the regex in question:

```
([0-9]{1,4}[A-Z]?)|([A-Z])|(^$)
```

Simple enough eh?

I'm using these tools to test my regex:
[Regex Analyzer](http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws)
[Regex Validator](http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/)

Here are the expected results:

- Valid

  - "1234A"
  - "Z"
  - "(Empty string)"
- Invalid

  - "A1234"
  - "fhfdsahds527523832dvhsfdg"

Obviously if I'm here, the invalid ones are accepted by the regex. The goal of this regex is accept either 1 to 4 numbers with an optional letter, or a single letter or an empty string.

I just can't seem to figure out what's not working, I mean it is a simple enough regex we have here. I'm probably missing something as I'm not very good with regexes, but this syntax  seems ok to my eyes. Hopefully someone here can point to my error.

Thanks for all help, it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `^` and `$` anchors for your first two options as well. Also you can include the second option into the first one (which immediately matches the third variant as well):

```
^[0-9]{0,4}[A-Z]?$
```

Without the anchors your regular expression matches because it will just pick a single letter from anywhere within your string.

Comment: Gah. I was about to post that exact regex (but with the capture group) ;-)

Comment: I left it out, because he only wanted to validate (and the capture group will be exactly the same as the full match). ;)

Comment: What is the capture group by the way? What is it for? Also perfect answer I'll be accepting as soon as it unlocks.

Comment: When you use `(` brackets `)` around parts of your regex you will be able to retrieve those parts separately later on (how exactly depends on the technology/language you are using).

Comment: one thing I noticed on yours, is the string `1234562A` would still match against the `1234`.  If you change the `?$` to `{1}$`, then it will only allow 4 numbers followed by a letter, or a single letter. The way I read his example, it seems like that's what he wanted.

Comment: @Nick since I use both the `^` and the `$` anchor, there can't be anything else but up to 4 digits and zero or one letter. Or what did you mean?

Comment: Using `(^[0-9]{1,4}[A-Z]?$)|(^[A-Z]$)|(^$)` it doesn't seem to accept 1234562A at all

Comment: I'm not sure why, but when I put it into GoSkinner, it validated the first 4 numbers on the 123455A.  I just rechecked and I must have misscopied something, because now it works like expected. It's been a long day, sorry about that.

Comment: According to your question you only want up to 4 digits, don't you?

Comment: For the first group yes that's correct, with an optional letter

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't read it from your question that you want more than 4 digits in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the language, you can also use a negative look ahead.

```
^[0-9]{0,4}[A-Za-z](?!.*[0-9])
```

Breakdown:

```
^[0-9]{0,4}  =  This look for any number 0 through 4 times at the beginning of the string
[A-Za-z]     =  This look for any characters (Both cases)
(?!.*[0-9])  =  This will only allow the letters if there are no numbers anywhere after the letter.
```

I haven't quite figured out how to validate against a null character, but that might be easier done using tools from whatever language you are using.  Something along this logic:

```
if String Doesn't equal $null Then check the Rexex
```

Something along those lines, just adjusted for however you would do it in your language.

I used [RegEx Skinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to validate the answers.

Edit: Fixed error from comments

Comment: That will still match more than 4 letters at the beginning of the string if you don't use the `^` anchor. Or basically there could be anything at the beginning of the string.